# php post not working equal zero

Tags: php, forms, post

My form is not working
when I submit the form the names for example nickname dose not work it equals as a 0
when i try isset it shows true

```
   if(isset($_POST['name'])) {echo 'name!';} else {echo 'no!';}
```

```
    <form action="signup-form.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="form-signup">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" name="name" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nickname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nickname</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="nickname" class="form-control" id="nickname" placeholder="Nickname" name="nickname" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="signup_password" placeholder="Password" name="password" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm" name="confirm_password" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
                <?php 
                    // Recaptcha 
                    require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/include/recaptchalib.php");
                    $publickey = "6LcTBw8TAAAAAOriZNY3CS7nukStq1WbcGRmprRR"; // You got this from the signup page.
                    echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
                 ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Signup">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Check your input types. `nickname` is not a valid type.

Comment: you have some html error it should be like  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nickname" placeholder="Nickname" name="nickname" />
            </div>

Comment: For a debug session, you can replace the form method with GET so that you can see visually what gets submitted exactly..

Answer (score 1):

Several things, your HTML is invalid (though I'm not sure it's breaking it) please use appropriate type values in your input fields. For name and nickname, the valid type value is "text", not "name" or "nickname" those belong as values of the name and id tags for those inputs.

Using isset will be true even if the variable is an empty string, because the $_POST variable will have that variable, just probably empty so isset passes, you want to check for an empty string I think (use empty() for that)